# sb cannot be resolved to a variable

Tags: java

I tried this code, which works for other people, but doesn't for me:

```
//import java.lang.*;


public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String[][] states = new String[3][2];   
        states[0][0]="california";
        states[0][1]="scremanto";
        states[1][0]="oregan";
        states[1][1]="salem";
        states[2][0]="newyork";
        states[2][1]="chicago";

        for (int i = 0; i < states.length; i++) {
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
            for (int j = 0; j < states[i].length; j++) {
                sb.append(states[i][j]);
            }
        }
        System.out.println(sb);
    }
}
```

And the error I get is :

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation problem: 
>       sb cannot be resolved to a variable
>
> at Main.main(Main.java:23)

Note: I work with Eclipse, maybe it's meaningful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> other people dont have this problem

You probably overlooked some of the brackets that end the class, method, and outer for loop...

Depending on what you want to print, you have to use your variables "in scope".

```
for (int i = 0; i < states.length; i++) {
    // locally scoped to the for loop 
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    for (int j = 0; j < states[i].length; j++) {
        sb.append(states[i][j]);
    }
    System.out.println(sb); // will work here 
}

System.out.println(sb); // but not here
```

Or

```
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
for (int i = 0; i < states.length; i++) {
    for (int j = 0; j < states[i].length; j++) {
        sb.append(states[i][j]);
    }
    System.out.println(sb); // will still work here 
}

System.out.println(sb); // and now works here
```

Note: you're appending strings immediately onto each other without a new line character.

Answer (score 2):

You define `sb` inside the `i` for and attempt to reference it outside it, which, as you see, won't work. Seems like you meant to define it outside the loop:

```
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
for (int i = 0; i < states.length; i++) {
    for (int j = 0; j < states[i].length; j++) {
        sb.append(states[i][j]);
    }
}

System.out.println(sb);
```

Comment: thanks alot, thats work for me , but can u explain why that code work for my friend without any problem ?